# Does the userservicefactory in GAE only work for people with g-mail accounts?

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, authentication, web

I am trying to create a login function for my application.

I am wondering whether I can use the userservicefactory that GAE offers to create a login user ID for someone that wants to register and login whenever they please?

I have only seen the userservicefactory used when people have gmail accounts.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrated user service of GAE is configured, by default, for google accounts. But that is not the only option. [As the documentation states](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/?hl=en), you can also have [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) or Google Apps authentication. It does not, however, support a custom user database. You would have to write that yourself.

Comment: I am a little weak with user databases. What exactly would a customer user database allow me to do over the integrated user GAE server? Would it be suitable to write a user database using the datastore that GAE offers?

Comment: Not "customer", "custom" ;) Anyway, like I said, the integrated user service of GAE only supports Google accounts, Google Apps accounts and OpenID. If you just want people to be able to register/login for your site, you would have to write that yourself, using the datastore, as you suggested.

Comment: A quick question, if I used an OpenID method could I still provide the user with more attributes such as having paid a monthly fee etc?

Comment: Not directly, but you could store such data in a separate entity in the datastore, using the [UserId](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User#getUserId%28%29) property of the `User` object as a key. Btw, if you're gonna use the datastore, [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) is well worth a look.

Comment: Ok thanks, I appreciate the help mate! I have had a look at objectify and it looks fairly good, gonna have a mess around with it this evening. Another related question - when a user is logged into the website, are they sent a cookie with their UserID (or similar) so that the page can querie the datastore whether he is logged in or not? How else would the website know that he is logged in? (I know this is probably all simple for you but I am self taught in the last 6 months on Java, javascript, HTML, CSS, GAE etc etc. so I am asking fairly stupid questions)

Comment: Yes, the user system uses cookies. But it is all done automatically, behind the scenes, so to say. All you need to worry about is asking the user service for the current user. If it is null, no one is logged in. If it isn't, you will get the currently logged in user. No need to do anything yourself.

Comment: By the way, do feel free to post additional questions you have as new questions, instead of comments to this answer. I am not the only one who is able to help you, and you will get your answers quicker when you're not waiting for me to go online :)

Comment: Haha yeah sorry, Thank you again its making more sense now :)